# Five div boxes, two on a row and the fifth one on top of the four - how do I do this in css?

Tags: html, css, design-patterns

This is what I have to do and I have  no idea how to do it, i  can create the four divs, but the fifth one is giving me trouble.

Here is what I need to do: create five divs, four of them need to be grouped in two, and the fifth one needs to be placed on top of the four divs. I have attached an image so you can better understand.

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msr4K.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a bunch of ways. I would create a parent element with a `flex` `row` layout set to `wrap` and `position: relative`, then let the 4 children occupy the parent, the absolutely position the 5th over the 4.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
div > div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 50vh;
  background: red;
}
div > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
div > div:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
div > div:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
}
div > div:last-child {
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 50vh;;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to get that done, one such is here:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="block a"></div>
   <div class="block b"></div>
   <div class="block c"></div>
   <div class="block d"></div>
   <div class="upperBlock"></div>
</div>

<style>
   .block{display:inline-block;width:50%;float:left;height:80px}
   .a{background:red;}
   .b{background:blue;}
   .c{background:black;}
   .d{background:gold;}
   .parent{position:relative;height:160px;}
   .upperBlock{height:80px;width:80px;position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);background:white;}
</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vy7th0es/